# extjs3 Grid cell maxlength input validation

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, grid, extjs3

I have a EditorGridPanel that grid cell want to validation to prevent from entering more characters into cell fields than the max length limit of cell. when user try to enter more than max limit that remove extra characters(it's like  Twitter's input box) how can i do in extjs?

Answer (score 0):

In your column configuration you can define editor for column. There you can set `Ext.form.TextField` as column editor. In textfield configuration you can define max length limit by [`maxLength`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-cfg-maxLength) config property.

Column configuration:

```
{
   ...
   editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
       maxLength: 25
   }),
   ...
}
```

Comment: `MyTextField1Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.form.NumberField, {
    name: 'name',
    decimalPrecision: 0,
    allowDecimals: false,
    allowBlank: false,
    maxLength: 33,
    id: 'my_id',
    initComponent: function() {
        MyTextField1Ui.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});` as i did for validation but that not worked for me. it's not validate like what i describe in question. thanks for your great effect